# Salvar o caminho de uma imagem no banco de dados usando asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Eu quero selecionar uma imagem e salvar no banco de dados o caminho da imagem, pois no banco sql a coluna "Imagem" esta com o tipo `varchar`. Poderiam me ajuda com alguns exemplos? Desde já agradeço.

View para Inserir:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Adicionar Sistema</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataInativo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataInativo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataInativo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BoletoConfigId, "BoletoConfigId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BoletoConfigId, TempData["BoletoConfigId"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Selecione", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BoletoConfigId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UrlAcesso, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UrlAcesso, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UrlAcesso, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Imagem, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" id="imagem" name="imagem"/>
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Imagem, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Imagem, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Adicionar" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Inserir()
{
   ViewBag.BoletoConfigId = new 
   SelectList(RepositorioBase<BancoBoletoConfiguracao>.GetAll(), 
   "BoletoConfigId", "Descricao");
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Inserir(Sistema sistema)
{   
   RepositorioBase<Sistema>.Add(sistema);
   return RedirectToAction("Listar");
}
```

Comment: Cade o seu código, a sua View? o seu código que grava na tabela... ?

Comment: Agora estão ai! @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551528/httppostedfilebase-always-return-null-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216605/salvar-o-caminho-de-uma-imagem-no-banco-de-dados-usando-asp-net-mvc-5?noredirect=1#comment442857_216605